# Firebase invite failling when sending emails

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-invites

My app started to fail sending invitations. The invitation screen popups and when the sender press send to send emails to the selected contacts it receive the error

> Message Failed to send

I try everything i could remember, checking connection, use other google account, and even build a small app that only sends invitations.
The only thing i can find that gives a clue about the error is the following log entry's:

> 05-05 19:56:41.191 1409-1409/? D/SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name:
>   changing
>   com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.appinvite.AppInviteActivity
>   to 
>   com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.appinvite.AppInviteActivity#3
>
> ...
>
> 05-05 19:56:41.411 3254-4228/? E/Volley: [216]
>   BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for
>   https://www.googleapis.com/plusdatamixer/v1/mutateonekey?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyAP-gfH3qvi6vgHZbSYwQ_XHqV_mXHhzIk

There are about 10 log entry's generated after pressing send, but only these 2 seems relevant.

Here is the full code from my test app, copy from documentation, in case i fail somewhere:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_INVITE = 1002;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private void onInviteClicked() {
        Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(getString(R.string.invitation_title))
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.invitation_message))
                .setDeepLink(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invitation_deep_link)))
             //   .setCustomImage(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invitation_custom_image)))
                .setCallToActionText(getString(R.string.invitation_cta))
                .build();
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);
    }

    public void click(View view) {
        onInviteClicked();
    }
}
```

The dependencies are the ones added automatically by android builder. Here a snapshot of the gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I am stuck in this for a few hours and still clueless. Any pointer?

Update:
The app and the test project can send invites successfully on my physical android, that runs API 21. Running the app in a android simulator with API 21 still fails, so it points that the service is constrained to physical devices, but during the week i tested successfully on virtual devices.
Also, there is nothing supporting that the service is restricted, so i must be doing something wrong.

**Update 6-May-2018:**
Just updated to the invites package to `com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.1` and still got the same error, but preceded by:

```
W/GLSUser: [AppCertManager] IOException while requesting key: 
    java.io.IOException: Invalid device key response.
        at gga.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):12)
        at gga.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):64)
        at gga.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):21)
        at gfy.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):4)
        at gfy.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:627)
        at cwl.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):3)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
W/GLSUser: [DeviceKeyStore] Cannot load key: Device key file not found.
E/Volley: [220] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/plusdatamixer/v1/mutateonekey?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyAP-gfH3qvi6vgHZbSYwQ_XHqV_mXHhzIk
```